# How to get contents from Iframe into PDF

Tags: jsp, iframe, pdf-generation

I am trying to use iFrame display the web page and it is displaying so perfectly but when i use the same for generating the PDF, the PDF is coming blank.

Please suggest if it is possible for PDF to have iFrame contents or not?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question with necessary code? Do you want to display PDF file in iFrame?

Comment: Actually i have a JSP which conatins an Iframe and displays the contents in browser of that iFrame but when try to generate PDF for those frame contents, PDF comes blank.

Comment: Can you post the code, how you're generating the PDF?

Comment: <iframe id = "form-iframe" src="some extrnal URL" width="775px" height="900px" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="margin-top: -10px; margin-left: -6px; " onload="onLoadHandler();"></iframe>                            and this iframe output is printed on jsp using out.ptintln() and this jsp contents are sent to generate the pdf to PD4ML